# Matplotlib line and bar in the same chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe with this easy structure:

| Month | Energy | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 10 | 0.5 |
| Feb | 11 | 0.6 |
| March | 13 | 0.71 |
| April | 15 | 0.73 |
| May | 18 | 0.81 |
| June | 20 | 0.85 |
| July | 24 | 0.91 |
| August | 28 | 0.93 |
| September | 24 | 0.81 |
| November | 17 | 0.71 |
| December | 15 | 0.6 |

And I want to plot the energy in bar and the percentaje in a line all in the same chart with two Y axis one for the Energy and other for the percentage. The final result I want to seems like in the picture below:

[image: Chart]

I'm also interested in show the fixed axis X with all the months even if this month doesnt have values yet

Hope you can help me
Thanks!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825950/matplotlib-create-two-subplots-in-line-with-two-y-axes-each

Answer (score 0):

The code below solves your problem. So basically using the twinx() function you are able to create the 2nd access on the same plot. I copied and pasted the data you provided in your question to an excel file named Book1.xlsx.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx")

df['Percentage'] = df['Percentage'] * 100

# create figure and axis objects with subplots()
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(60, 50))

# make a plot
ax.plot(df.Month, df.Percentage, 
        marker="o",
        color="red")
# set x-axis label
ax.set_xlabel("Months", fontsize = 14)
# set y-axis label
ax.set_ylabel("Percentage",
              color="red",
              fontsize=14)


# twin object for two different y-axis on the sample plot
ax2=ax.twinx()
# make a plot with different y-axis using second axis object
ax.bar(df.Month ,df.Energy )
ax2.set_ylabel("Energy",color="blue",fontsize=14)


plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks man, I tried but for expample, like in this case, the november and december month don't have data I would like to see in the X Axis the mont and nothing in the bars and line. With this code everythin is adapted only for the months with data.